# MYSQL-Got different result when use sum(case when condition 1) and count(case when condition 1)

Tags: mysql

I used the following query to count row I wonder when I use sum() in the query it returns correct but when I use count return false. I complete that work but I need this clarification for further development of myself

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
         WHEN g.branchid=30  THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS count FROM `liverates` l LEFT JOIN branch b ON b.warehouseid=l.warehouseid LEFT JOIN `group` g ON l.warehouseid=g.warehouseid

SELECT COUNT(CASE 
         WHEN g.branchid=30  THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS count FROM `liverates` l LEFT JOIN branch b ON b.warehouseid=l.warehouseid LEFT JOIN `group` g ON l.warehouseid=g.warehouseid
```

Above SUM() return 215 correct result then count() doesn't return actual result it was returned the total count of table

Answer (score 2):

`count()` counts all non-null values, no matter what they are. So `0` is counted as well.

This would work with `count()`

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN g.branchid=30  
           THEN 1
           ELSE NULL
       END)
```

or just leave the `else` part

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN g.branchid=30  
           THEN 1
       END)
```

Especially in MySQL you could simplify your `sum()` like that (since the result of a condition is either `1` or `0`)

```
SUM(g.branchid=30)
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` will count the number of rows it encounters, so even if the value is manipulated to be 1 or 0 by your `case`, it is still a row and so will be counted.

If you just want the rows where `g.branchid=30` then turn it into a `WHERE` clause...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
    FROM `liverates` l 
    LEFT JOIN branch b ON b.warehouseid=l.warehouseid 
    LEFT JOIN `group` g ON l.warehouseid=g.warehouseid
    WHERE g.branchid=30
```

this will ignore rows which it isn't interested in and may use an index.  You may also be able to remove the link to the branch table as this doesn't look as though it is relevant in this case...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
    FROM `liverates` l 
    LEFT JOIN `group` g ON l.warehouseid=g.warehouseid
    WHERE g.branchid=30
```